# Add large number of objects to class in loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to set up a class which has a large number of similarly-named objects associated with it. At the moment, the code looks like the following:

```
class Larva():
    i0 = Variable(param1, param2, param3)
    i1 = Variable(param1, param2, param3)
    i2 = Variable(param1, param2, param3)
    ...
    i99 = Variable(param1, param2, param3)
```

Where `Variable` is another class.

I know that the obvious response is 'just replace all of those separate variables with a list'. However, this `Larva` class is itself an input to a different, highly complex python package, and that package *requires* that these objects all be separate. Unfortunately, there is nothing that I can do about this.

I'd therefore like to know whether there is anyway to automate the creation of these instances within `Larva` (i.e. in a loop), which would make my code a lot less cluttered.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `self.i0`, `self.i1`, etc?

Comment: He was defining those at class level, so the `self` isn't necessary.

Comment: Oh.  You're right.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.  `setattr` is less hated than dinking with `globals`:

```
    def __init__(self):
        for i in range(100):
            setattr( self, f"i{i}", Variable(param1, param2, param3) )
```

Comment: But (in the general case) using `setattr` for this is worse than just using a dict.

Comment: Also, this creates instance attributes, not class attributes.

Comment: So yes, you want `setattr(Larva, f"i{i}", ....)`.  But using `setattr` is the accepted way of doing this sort of stuff when you have no alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you really do need to dynamically create class attributes, not instance attributes, you can just declare the class and `setattr` them into place.

```
class Larva:
    pass  # ...


for x in range(50):
    setattr(Larva, f'i{x}', complex(x, x + 1))

print(Larva.i8)  # prints (8+9j)
```

This won't necessarily work if your `Larva` has e.g. a metaclass (or a superclass with `__init_subclass__`) that deals with these attributes, since the metaclass may not see them "early enough" since they're created after the class is created.

In that case, you would need to call the metaclass itself with a dynamic `attrs` (the signature is the same for `type`, which you'd use for dynamically creating classes):

```
class Metaclass(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        if not all(f'a{x}' in attrs for x in range(1, 6)):
            raise ValueError('This metaclass requires all of a1..5')
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)


class Larva(metaclass=Metaclass):
    a1 = 123
    a2 = 123
    a3 = 123
    a4 = 123
    a5 = 123


DynamicLarva = Metaclass('DynamicLarva', (), {f'a{x}': x * 50 for x in range(1, 6)})

print(Larva.a1)  # 123
print(DynamicLarva.a3)  # 150
```